# ValidationError "value must be a decimal number"

Tags: django

I have a model

```
class FunderProgramMember(models.Model):
buyer = models.IntegerField()
supplier = models.IntegerField()
discount_rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=3, decimal_places=2)
```

In my serializer I am trying to get the discount field:

```
discount_rate = FunderProgramMember.objects.values('discount_rate').get(supplier=item.invoice.supplier_id, buyer=item.invoice.buyer)
```

Even if I replace my filter "get(supplier=item.invoice.supplier_id, buyer=item.invoice.buyer)" with pk=2
I still receive the following validation error:
["“{'discount_rate': Decimal('0.25')}” value must be a decimal number."]

It appears to get a decimal value. How do I fix this error?

Comment: Can you share your `invoice` model? Why did you use `IntegerFields` instead of `ForeignKey`s? Can you share the entire view, it looks like the error of your second attempt is situated later in the view.

Comment: Try `from decimal import Decimal` and covert the value you got before reassignment : `dicount_rate  = Decimal(discount_rate)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you work with the `.supplier_id` and `buyer_id`, then the query will succeed, since the fields are `IntegerField`s. Likely the rest of the view rases the exception.

This is because your `discount_rate` is not a `Decimal` object, but a dictionary containing that item. You can work with [**`.values_list(…, flat=True)`** [Django-doc]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) to retrieve a scalar result:

```
discount_rate = FunderProgramMember.objects.values_list('discount_rate', flat=True).get(
    supplier=item.invoice.supplier_id, buyer=item.invoice.buyer
)
```

I would further advise to work with `ForeignKey`s instead of `IntegerField`s: `ForeignKey`s will guarantee referential integrity and make it more convenient to work with the Django ORM.

Comment: Thank you, that did work. Using FK instead of int would make my code much simpler overall. But I would have required a composite key since the supplierid and buyerid are unique together in my FunderProgramMember model.

Comment: @Basquiat: you can make use of Django's constraint framework for this: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/constraints/